# Representing a Google Form in LaTeX appendix?

Tags: appendix, forms

I have collected some data using Google forms for my master's thesis. I would like to represent these forms in my Appendix and was wondering if there were any available tools to make that transition. I would rather not stitch screenshots together or write down every question by hand.

Comment: Are the results saved in a spreadsheet? Perhaps you could save that as a csv-file and display that with the `datatool` package. Might depend on what the results look like though ..

Comment: Maybe printed to PDF from the browser and including that PDF in your LaTeX document would be an option.

Comment: I decided to use the includepdf package to simply display the pdfs. The Google Forms translated very badly to pdf, but got the job done.